How to convert a single BsonValue, such as "BsonArray" to json in the Java bson library
I am developing a function to import ChangStream into aws redshift. I need to convert the value of the composite field type (such as: BsonArray, BsonDocument) in mongodb into a JSON string.
The Java bson library can only convert BsonDocument to JSON string (using toJson method), but other composite field types such as BsonArray are not supported
For example, the following code
BsonArray bsonArray = new BsonArray();
bsonArray.add(new BsonString("apple"));
bsonArray.add(new BsonString("banana"));
bsonArray.add(new BsonString("orange"));

I want it to output as:
["apple","banana","orange"]

I tried:
BsonArray bsonArray = new BsonArray();
bsonArray.add(new BsonString("apple"));
bsonArray.add(new BsonString("banana"));
bsonArray.add(new BsonString("orange"));

StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();

JsonWriter jsonWriter = new JsonWriter(stringWriter);

jsonWriter.writeStartArray();
for (int i = 0; i < bsonArray.size(); i++) {
    jsonWriter.writeString(bsonArray.get(i).toString());
}
jsonWriter.writeEndArray();
jsonWriter.flush();

String jsonString = stringWriter.toString();

System.out.println("JSON: " + jsonString);

But:
Exception in thread "main" org.bson.BsonInvalidOperationException: A StartArray value cannot be written to the root level of a BSON document.

MongoDB data always is a document (document can have composite fields like array or objects/sub-document). An array in MongoDB is always stored as a field (of type array). You cannot create an array as MongoDB document.

Here is a similar question as this post with an answer: Java BsonArray to json string.

Does this answer your question? BSON to JSON conversion using MongoDB Driver Java API

@prasad_ Thank you, I want to convert arrays to JSON strings for easy storage in other databases

@冲天炮 You may just want to try using the Java JSON library like Gson: Gson User Guide - Array Examples . This will convert a Java Array to a JSON.
